# interpret NetStat -a for a postgres remote connection

Tags: postgresql, tcp, connection, netstat

When I run netstat -a | findstr :5432  I get:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           PDDV-Answers:0         LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         PDDV-Answers:53925     ESTABLISHED
...
TCP    127.0.0.1:53931        PDDV-Answers:5432      ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::]:5432              PDDV-Answers:0         LISTENING
```

Is the postgres  DB on this server listening for remote connections on 5432?
I was expecting something like:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           *.*:0         LISTENING
```

My settings in postgres have all been enabled for remote connections and listening. and I think my firewall rule in is place - yet I can't remote telnet to the server on 5432 (local telnet to it works), or establish a database connection from my remote server which is my ultimate objective.

Comment: have you checked your `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: Which operating system is this? (Different OS, different `netstat`, different results). It seems pretty clear that Pg is listening on IPv4 and IPv6 port 5432 on all interfaces, though.

Answer (score 0):

Craig Ringer was correct. The system is listening fine. There was a corporate firewall which was blocking access into the server.

In addition I needed to add additional access rules via the pg_hba.conf file for the servers own IP number

```
host    all             all             a.b.c.d/32            md5
```

To allow it to connect to itself via Telnet. That was how I proved it was a corporate firewall problem